# What is the purpose of SelectMany(x => x)?

Tags: c#, lambda

I understand the use of lambda functions as a filter such as `(x => x.Count() == 1)`, but what is the purpose of the `(x => x)`? When I take it out, the code doesn't compile, and every example of lambda functions I can find seems to use it to filter in one line instead of multiple lines without the lambda.

```
List<Tuple<int, int>> regVals = ReadRegValCollection.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

The purpose of this gem is to flatten a List of Lists into a List

Comment: `x => x` returns x (it is also known as the identity function), so look at in context. *What does SelectMany do?* That's the question/answer - and the docs should provide sufficient information. It doesn't matter if it's `x => x` or `x => f(x)`.

Comment: Perhaps you should familiarize yourself with the [`SelectMany()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method first... then you can reevaluate whether or not it is confusing.

Comment: It's equivalent to *Haskell*'s [`concat`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:concat)...

Comment: @JeffMercado SelectMany() returns a flattened list, so is the (x => x).ToList() only needed for syntax or to get the datatype to match? I don't quite get it.

Answer (score 18):

`x => x` is a lambda expression that returns whatever argument it's provided with.

It's equivalent to a method declared as

```
public T Identity<T>(T item)
{
    return item;
}
```

It's commonly used with `SelectMany` method to flatten a collection declared as `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` into `IEnumerable<T>`.

`SelectMany` requires a delegate that matches `Func<IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TResult>>`. In case when a source is `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` and you want a result to be `IEnumerable<T>` no projection has to be done on source collection elements, as they already are `IEnumerable<TResult>`.